# Angular reapply table striping after hiding rows

Tags: css, angular, sass

I've got a table that needs to be striped but it has some rows that may become hidden later on. After hiding some of the rows re-striping does not occur so the striping is off. How can I force the table to re-stripe itself? Here is my css that I feel should work, but it's not. And then also my html.

```
.isHidden {
    display:none;
}

tbody {
    tr:not(.isHidden):nth-child(odd) {
        background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    }
}

<tbody>
        <tr [ngClass]="{'isHidden': !line.get('isVisible').value}" *ngFor="let line of lineDetailsArray.controls; let i=index;">
...
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: nth-of-type is behaving the same as nth-child. All of my rows do not have 'isHidden' at the beginning and the table is perfectly striped, but then as the rows become hidden the striping is messed up because the table isn't being re-striped. And I can't use *ngIf because I'm already using *ngFor to cycle through my list.

Comment: Angular version 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, you won't be able to solve the problem with CSS only, unfortunately. True, there's a potentially useful addition [in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) - `:nth-child(An+B of S)`. [The following example](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#example-16753530) exactly matches your case:

> Normally, to zebra-stripe a table’s rows, an author would use CSS
>   similar to the following:

```
tr {
  background: white;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: silver;
}
```

> However, if some of the rows are hidden and not displayed, this
>   can break up the pattern, causing multiple adjacent rows to have the
>   same background color. Assuming that rows are hidden with the `[hidden]`
>   attribute in HTML, the following CSS would zebra-stripe the table rows
>   robustly, maintaining a proper alternating background regardless of
>   which rows are hidden:

```
tr {
  background: white;
}
tr:nth-child(even of :not([hidden])) {
  background: silver;
}
```

The caveat? Support of this option in browsers is not even limited: it's [non-existent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child#Browser_compatibility).

---

But still, there's a way out of this misery. Even though Angular won't just let you place `ngIf` and `ngFor` on a single element (it'll be way too simple I suppose), there's a workaround - using `<ng-container>` as a placeholder:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!item.hidden">
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" 
                [checked]="item.hidden" 
                (change)="item.hidden = !item.hidden" /></td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6yu5m?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) (kudos to [@imkremen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2892505/imkremen) for helping to create this one).